# Sprockets Best Practice for big projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, optimization, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have been working for several months on a RoR project with fellows university students. I am responsible for the frontend and assets part and I found myself wondering **how to use Sprockets the best way**.

The point of having an asset pipeline is to boost performance in terms of page loading time. The way a Rails generated app does it is to put all the stylesheets and javascripts into two compressed files.

But when the app volume and complexity grow this IMHO becomes a bad idea, because the size of the all-in-one file grows and there may be problems with overlapping css rules or scripts that look for an element and doesn't find it, making the whole javascript part of the page crash.

**Note:** I am aware that with good coding rules and convention among the team the occurrence of those problems can be decreased, but not down to 0.

Am I right with these assertion so far?

If positive then **what's a good way to handle big projects without serving lots of rules or scripts useless for the scope of the page, without losing the benefits of few assets to send to the client?**

My current approach is to define a set of all-in-one files, one per each "context area" of the application. So basically I try to send 2+2 files.

But then how to handle cases like this:

> There is a very simple index view for a resource with just the list of entries, each linked to the respective show. The show instead is not simple at all, it has lots of CSS3 rules and javascript.

With my approach the index action will have a lot of unused code. How do you handle your big projects?

Do you give more importance to what resources a page gets or to the performance?

Another thing that bothers me is **how to handle partials**. In an object oriented design each partial should (?) have all the includes it needs to work correctly everywhere it's loaded. But this would result in duplicated includes if I call the `javascript_include_tag` for the same asset in both the view and the partial.

Do all these thoughts of mine make sens or am I missing something? Or may be looking at the problem from the wrong perspective? Can you suggest me some links or open source projects to take a look at? What's your opinion on the matter?

Thanks and sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Starting with best-practice (Tier one code):**

Have two files, precompiled (minified/compressed), served with server compression and far-future headers. As a result of the headers these files will be cached by the client browser on the first request, and used for all pages after that until the cache expires, or is purged.

The files may also be cached by transparent proxies; ISPs use these to speed up the net for their customers. That'll further reduce requests.

So from a performance point of view only the first request is expensive.

**Admin section (Tier two code)**

It is very common in sites with an admin section to spin that off into a separate pair of files. Admin might use jquery-ui while the public site does not. In that case this is the best compromise - you dont want to serve a completely un-used library for every public request.

The Rails pipeline guide mentions how to set this up.

**Page code (Tier three)**

The third layer is for page specific js and css (your question).

In that case you are going to have to make a call on the performance/maintenance side of things. If you have many bits of code you want to separate out all of these have to be added to the assets pipeline precompile array. If there are many or the code is small this is a pain.

Needing (or wanting) to do this can be a signal to you, the programmer, that the overall design of the CSS could be improved. If you are having to add lots of extra rules for specific pages, then you may not be using the CASCADE (the C in CSS) as well as you might. :-)

Object Oriented CSS is one answer to this problem. As a disciple it is about defining reusable blocks of CSS that can be used everywhere. If that is done, then small numbers of page specific rules are less of a problem from a performance (including them for all pages) or maintenance point of view.

If you must have a separate file for a page then following the pipeline best practices for these files will at least not trade off the cacheability of the files.

What I do in my projects is provide some helpers that allow views to stack up files and code for the main application layout. The benefit of this is I get to control where the generated code appears, rather then being mid-page, which is what happens if you include the files in a view partial. (That is very bad for page rendering performance as mid-page file includes block rendering)

I do this:

application_helper.rb

```
def deferred_javascript(&block)
  @deferred_javascript ||= []

  if block_given?
    @deferred_javascript << capture(&block)
  end

  @deferred_javascript
end

def deferred_javascript_files
    @javascript_includes ||= []
end

def deferred_css_files
    @stylesheet_includes ||= []
end
```

And then in a view:

```
<% deferred_javascript_files << 'extras/public_form' %>
<% deferred_css_files << 'extras/public_form' %>
```

or I can use a block with the deferred_javascript helper if it is a one-liner. (I use this very rarely).

The public_form files are manifests for stuff required for this form (jquery-ui, formtastic) that is not need on any other page.

NB: Any files used in this way must be added to the precompile array:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['extras/public_form.css', 'extras/public_form.js']
```

It is easy to forget because my method works in development mode without, but will fail when you deploy in production!

Lastly in the application layout, at the top (in the head tag) for CSS:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('application', :media => 'all' ) -%>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag(deferred_css_files) if deferred_css_files.any? %>
```

and at the bottom of the layout (before the closing body tag) for JS:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $(document).ready(function() {
<%= raw deferred_javascript.join("\n") %>
  });
<%- end unless deferred_javascript.blank? -%>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>  
<%= javascript_include_tag(deferred_javascript_files) if deferred_javascript_files.any? %>
```

This lines add the main manifests, and any view manifests and code.

What I have outlined ensures that any view-added files are part of the pipeline and have the same chance of being cached as the main files.

**To summarize:**

Putting everything in the main manifests is almost always The Right Thing To Do, however when the page-specific code is very large it can be moved into a separate file and served as I've outlined. You will have to make the performance call on which approach is better - not having that extra code on every page, or the extra file request on the one page.